# How to stop a div loading an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The `remove()` on id **main** is called from clicking another external button. The problem is if the user clicks `btn1` and quickly presses that external button, the remove is getting called before the event handler for `btn1`. As a result of which the popup is loaded after the div has been removed. Is there a way by which the load request can be stopped when event handler for remove is clicked? I tried with `jqXHR.abort()` when remove method is called,but that doesn't work because the remove is called before the ajax is even sent.

There are many buttons like btn1 which will send ajax requests to load HTML and Few HTMlL files for e.g `a.html` will load some script files like `a.js`, which will be executed. And if the script refers to some variable which was deleted in `remove()`, there will be a TypeError.

```
<div id="base">
    <div id="main">
        <!-- some more HTML elements -->
        <button id="btn1"></button>
    </div>
    <div id ="popup">
    </div>
</div>

<script>  
    var xhr;      
    $("#btn1").on("click", function(){
        xhr = $.ajax(
        url: "a.html",
        success: function(){
             //do something
        }),
        type: "GET"
    });

    $("#main").on("remove", function(){
       // delete all resources,etc.
       xhr.abort();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you disable your external button on btn1 click and enable it in the 'done' callback of the ajax method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a global variable

```
var removed = 0;
$('externabutton').click(function(){
  $("#main").remove();
   removed = 1;
});
 $("#btn1").on("click", function(){
        xhr = $.ajax(
        url: "a.html",
        success: function(data){
             if (removed == 0 ) {
              //append the data
             } else {removed ==0;}
        }),
        type: "GET"
    });
```

Comment: I have edited the question to give more information about the problem. global variable `removed` will allow not to append the data to HTML but still the script will be loaded.

Comment: what script,how is it load?

Comment: `<html><head></head><body><script>$.getScript("a.js")</script></body></html>`.

Comment: what does this have to do with the ajax??\

Answer (score 0):

As the `xhr` is async, so we cannot guarantee the `xhr` is finished before `#main.remove` method. Maybe you could use a flag to control this.

```
var isRemoved = false, xhr;
$("#btn1").on("click", function(){
    if(isRemoved) return;
    xhr = $.ajax({
      url: "a.html",
      success: function(){
           //do something
        if(isRemoved) return;
      },
      type: "GET"
   });
 });

$("#main").on("remove", function(){
   isRemoved = true;
   xhr && xhr.abort();
});
```